# Плагин tablesorter jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Поддерживает ли tablesorter сортировку вложенных таблиц ? Например, такая конструкция

```
    <tr class='test'>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>

        //Вложенная строка
        <tr class="test2">
            <td colspan="5">text</td>
        </tr>

    </tr>
```

Если возможно, приведите пример, пожалуйста..или любой аналог плагина

Answer (score 1):

Нашел таки. Достаточно добавить класс tablesorter-childRow для вложенной строки.